# How to get contacts in alphabetical order using $cordovaContacts plugin of IONIC Framework

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm trying to build an app in Ionic Framework which fetches phone contacts using `$cordovaContacts` plugin. And everything works fine but how can I arrange these fetched contacts in alphabetical order i.e from A to Z. I know fetching contacts as per search keyword, but I'm not able to fetch the contacts in alphabetical order....

```
$cordovaContacts.find({filter : '', fields: ['displayName']}).then(function(allContacts) {
          for (var i = 0; i < allContacts.length ; i++) {
              $scope.Contacts.push({
                  cid  : allContacts[i]['id'],
                  cname: allContacts[i]['displayName'],
                  numbers: allContacts[i]['phoneNumbers']
              });
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch contacts,and add them to an array with push. Then you can use 
yourarray.sort() method to taxonomy in alphabetical order.

You can bind your new sorted array with scope variable.

```
$scope.newsortedarray = yourarray;
```

Then in your view:

```
   <ion-item ng-repeat="contact in newsortedarray track by $index">  
   <p>{{contact}}</p>
   </ion-item>
```